# An issue with Nearby Connection development

Tags: android, byte, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Indicates whether there is a restriction on the size of data blocks for Data objects of the Data.Type.BYTES type when data is received or transmitted. The test result shows that the transmission fails when the data in byte[] is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value of Data.type.BYTES in Nearby Connection is 32 KB.

Comment: There's one more detail I need to ask. 
When I send a file, are the data.gtId() of the sender and the data.getId() of the receiver the same ID? Or a different value? 
How does the receiver know the name of the file sent by the sender? 
Thanks

Comment: You are right. The IDs of the two sides must be the same to match each other.